# Windows 10 IoT Core UWP background application with App Service

Tags: uwp, windows-10-iot-core

Is it possible to have a UWP App Service in a Windows 10 IoT Core background app?

I used the [Windows IoT Core Project Template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MicrosoftIoT.WindowsIoTCoreProjectTemplatesforVS15) to create a background app that reads sensors on a timer, used the Windows 10 IoT dashboard to make the background app start automatically when the device powers up, and that all works fine. Now I want to make a GUI that can get the sensor data from the background app.

Using [the tutorial to create and consume an app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service), I learned some things about creating UWP App Services. I was able to get an app service to work when the app itself is a GUI/XAML app, and the code for the app service must be in a referenced UWP comonnent (`.winmd`). When the code for the app service is in the GUI app, every connection request returns `AppServiceUnavailable`. Similarly, when I try to add an app service to my Windows 10 IoT Core background app (a `.winmd` itself), all open connection attempts result in `AppServiceUnavailable`. I tried putting the app service code in a separate `.winmd`, but the same happens.

How can I get a GUI app to talk to a background app on the same device?

I found [instructions on how to enable localhsot (loopback) communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback), but it would be better if I could simply deploy the GUI and background apps without having to change the OS configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of implementing an app service in a background app on Windows IoT Core here: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/AppServiceSharedNotepad

Does that help?

Comment: The sample works for me. Now I have to figure out why my app is different, but at least I know it's technically possible. Thanks.

Comment: Turns out my problem was that I tried to use different entry point classes for the background task and the app service. It seems to only work when they use the same class. I find this very unintuitive, but at least I can work with it.